# Probability to draw 4 same cards with a hand of 17 cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Me and my friend were playing a game of three players with a 52 cards deck (17, 17, 18 card each), one of the player got 4 of the same type of card (four king), I told him that he is pretty lucky and he replied that it's not that unprobable

Doing simulation with a python code I find a probability of $P \approx 0.0088$

However I cannot reproduce this result by hand, I thought first that the probabilty would be

$$P = \frac{C^{4}_{17}}{C^{17}_{52}}$$

Which is a too small number to be relevant.

Going on the base that the probability of drawing 4 same type of card by just taking 4 card out of 52 is the inverse of $C_{52}^{4}$ I felt like I needed to multiply this combinaison by an another combinaison which would represent the number of hand I can have by taking more card but I cannot put this in mathematical terms

Would someone be able to clarify this ?

Comment: The probability of getting all four $K's$ in a $17$ card hand is $\binom {48}{13}\Big /\binom {52}{17}\approx  .00879$.

Comment: You answered my question thank you a lot !

Comment: As to how surprising this is, or isn't, note that the probability of getting at least one, unspecified $4-$of-a-kind is about $13\times .00879-\binom {13}2\times .006\approx .108$, where we are ignoring the (very small) chance of getting more than two $4-$-of-a-kinds.

Comment: Now., if you take it a step further and talk about *at least one* person (*not limited to specifically your friend*) having drawn *at least one* full set of *some* card (*not limited to one full set and not limited to kings*), the probability increases further.  The exact calculation for this becomes horribly tedious, but I'd estimate it at least $20\%-25\%$...  not that uncommon.

Comment: It should be noted that [improbable things happen](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Improbable_things_happen) quite often.

Comment: The expected number of four-of-a-kinds in all three hands is

$$
13\left(2\cdot\frac{\binom{48}{13}}{\binom{52}{17}}+\frac{\binom{48}{14}}{\binom{52}{18}}\right)=\frac{92}{245}\approx0.38\;.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting all four $K's$ in a $17$ card hand is $$\binom {48}{13}\Big /\binom {52}{17}\approx  .00879$$

What's the probability of getting any (unspecified) four of a kind?  Well, you can do it exactly using Inclusion-Exclusion.  We can approximate it quickly if we ignore the extremely small chance of getting $3$ or $4$ different four of a kinds. Under that approximation we get $$13\times .00879-\binom {13}2\times \binom {44}9\Big / \binom {52}{17}\approx .108$$

Which is fairly high.